# media query not working on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, media

The following code does not do anything on the iPad, despite that the font should be bigger in comparison with the desktop... How come?

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:landscape) {
.header {
font-family: courier new, monospace;
color: #999999;
font-size: 16pt;
line-height: 12pt;
width: 38.25em;
 }
}
.header {
font-family: courier new, monospace;
color: #999999;
font-size: 12pt;
line-height: 12pt;
width: 38.25em;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the @media query below the other header class, i believe the second header class is overwriting your media query

Comment: If I place @media below the other 'header' class the font becomes bigger on both devices; iPad as well as desktop. I am trying to get to this: 16pt font on iPad, and 12pt font on desktop.

Comment: I believe there are standards to what sizes to set these at, your default should be the bottom .header then you need a min and max for ipad, iphone etc, please see here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing if your media query is working at all? For example, changing the font to something completely different or background color to red. This way, you will know if it's the media query or a typo. If it is not a typo, add a max, separate arguments for your media query so the browser does not get confused, and you don't need to repeat code.

```
.header {
        font-family: courier new, monospace;
        color: #999999;
        line-height: 12pt;
        width: 38.25em;
        }

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and               (orientation:landscape
       {
       .header {
       font-size: 16pt;
          }
       }

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1025px) {
      .header {
      font-size: 12pt;
          }
       }
```

Comment: Many thanks, I could make it work with the instructions from the link above.